# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ModelManager'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, anaconda

When I install a new module with **pip install ModelManager** it says it downloaded successfully, then I check with pip list and its there and when I run my python code I get **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ModelManager'** error.

Comment: Try `pip3 install ModelManager` and `pip3 list` instead

Answer (score 0):

This could be an issue with your file name, or if you had multiple python versions on your computer.
But for the former problem, if your file name is ModelManager.py then changing it should fix it, but if you have the latter, then you should set up a proper environment for each of them, since their pip installs, install the module in the first python version you installed.